# Serve mirrored (static) web-page with original headers

Tags: http, wget, http-headers, mirroring

I have a dynamic webpage which I want to create a "frozen" copy of.

Typically I would do something like `wget -m http://example.com`, and then put the files in the document root of the web-server.

This site however has some dynamic content, including dynamically generated images, for instance

```
http://example.com/company/123/logo
```

This means that in order to mirror the page, I need to

1. Save whatever headers the server currently serves for each URL (at least which MIME types it reports).

   This can be done using the `wget` option `--save-headers`.
2. Serve the static pages *and* serve the proper headers (at least the content type headers) for each file.

   (This I have no idea of how to do.)

What is the best way to solve this? Any suggestions are welcome.

**Put differently:** How can I serve files without an extension with the correct MIME type header? (Where the original webserver defines what the *correct* MIME type really is.)

Comment: I don't see why you need to serve the original headers along with the "dynamic content".

Comment: Because a binary file such as `/company/123/logo` is not magically perceived as a jpeg by the browser without proper headers.

Comment: So the question you really *should* ask is "how can I serve files without an extension with the correct MIME type header?".

Comment: Yes. But there are som (extensioness) URLs pointing to zip files, some to files with html-content, javascript.content and so on. So instead of listing them all as you suggest, I would just like to preserv the headers. At least *some* headers.

Comment: I assume you're not talking to me when you say "listing them all as you suggest", because I *certainly* didn't suggest having a list of filename to MIME type mappings -- that would be stupid.

Comment: Woops. Was a bit quick on my reply. I thought you suggested to hard-code jpeg mime type for certain image files. Updated the question with your formulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the last bit of your question ("where the original server defines what the correct MIME type really is"), and you're using Apache, you can use [`mod_mime_magic`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) to automatically detect and serve the correct MIME type for your files.